# Raid drive disappearing from explorer

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, windows-server-2012

Ok, I've been starting to have an issue that is driving me mad recently and need some input.

SO I finally setup my very first raid array at home for my HTPC with the following specs.

Array: Raid10

OS:
Windows Server 2012

Mobo:
MSI H81I

CPU:
Intel i5 4670k

4 x HGST Deskstar 3TB NAS drives
[https://www.amazon.com/HGST-Deskstar-3-5-Inch-Internal-0S03660/dp/B00HHAJU7K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HHAJU7K)

Syba PEX40054 PCI-E Raid controller
http://www.sybausa.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=182

Rosewell 4 bay hotswap enclosure (it's outside my tiny mini atx case
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DGZ42SM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DGZ42SM)

So the raid is barely 4 days old, but when I was defragging as well as seemingly randomly the virtual drive for the raid would disappear from windows explorer, disk management. However, in MSU the controller was fine, device manager its fine, all drives are detected in MSU if I disconnect one it is registered as well as inserting one but does not cause anything to show back up elsewhere

However I can not get it to show back up unless I perform a restart. Considering this is a PLEX rig with friends and family using it when this goes down is quite a pain. So I do not think its the controller or the hotswap bay.

There is no error reported in MSU. However looking at event viewer I'm getting a few of these:

Application Log:
http://pastebin.com/A6LbPzqm

System Log:
http://pastebin.com/BUXb1PLM

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've attempted to use a suggestion in cmd net start "service" and it may help. Not sure until i check tomorrow after 8+ hours away. Usually wake up to this having occurred sometime over the night.

Comment: Still is happening, just did it when left to defrag overnight. Maybe the raid controller can't handle that much IO? VDS/VSS both crashed and so did marvell